# Async task not working

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jsoup

Hey i have a problem with my android application.I'm trying to download text from given url to Editable box but when i'm running application and hit the button it suddenly stops working.I am using asynctask to download, also eclipse tells me that class DownloadTask is not used locally

```
public void sendMessage(View view) throws IOException {
    new DownloadTask().execute();   
}

private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask{
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            EditText tf = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            String kupa = tf.getText().toString();
            Document doc;
            doc = Jsoup.connect(kupa).get();
            String title = doc.text();
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            tv.setText(title); 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
         tv.setText(result);
     }





}
```

Also i added two lines of code to my onCreate method

```
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

If this helps min api is 10,target is 16
cheers guys

Comment: try DownloadTask().execute((Void) null);

Comment: You can't have UI code in background since it is not executed with the main(ui) thread. tv.setText(title); 
Also for future questions, please include the StackTrace from LogCat, I am sure it will throw a exception clearly indicating you tried to run UI code on a non-ui thread.

Answer (score 1):

you can't run UI code in `doInBackground`.

you try run bellow code on `doInBackground`, delete that or move it to `onPostExecute`

```
tv.setText(title);
```

and you don't need following line:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

if you need value in `AyncTask` you can pass data, if you need `tf.getText().toString()` you can change your code with following code:

```
new DownloadTask().execute(tf.getText().toString());
```

and change AsyncTask class with:

```
public static class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params)
    // use params array, in this example you can get tf.getText().toString() with params[0]
       String kupa = params[0] // if you pass more data you can increase index
}
```

for more info see [documentation of AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 0):

:( Now, we can talk about Thread.
hmm...

You are using AsyncTask to download text from url.

It mean you are using another thread to do.

And another thread could not change UI. You must change UI in main thread. But if you want to change UI in other thread you can use **runOnUIThread** method.

I can give you a solution for your issue.

A child of **AsyncTask**

```
public class AsyncLoadData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private Context mContext;
    private ILoadDataListener mListener;

    public AsyncLoadData(Context context, ILoadDataListener listener) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String url = params[0];
        String result = doGetStringFromUrl(url); // You can write your own method;
                return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        mListener.complete(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mListener.loading();
    }

    public interface ILoadDataListener {
        void loading();

        void complete(String result);
    }
}
```

In your **activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AsyncLoadData.ILoadDataListener {
      /// Something...
     public void getData() {
         new AsyncLoadData(this, this).execute(url);
         // or new AsyncLoadData(getBaseContext(), this).execute(url);
     }

     @Override
     public void loading() {
        // Do something here when you start download and downloading text
     }

     @Override
     public void complete(String result) {
         TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_text_view);
         mTextView.setText(result);
         // EditText is the same.
     }
}
```